# How to add custom request headers that have pre-defined values for versioning purposes using the openapi spring server codegenerator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I have one endpoint that is mapped to one springboot application.

That endpoint is GET `/places` that returns a list of places.

I want to use a custom header called `x-api-version` that specifies which controller in my code should be used.

Simple example. If I send a request to GET /places and this header is supplied with a corresponding value `x-api-version=2` then that request should be directed to `PlacesControllerV2#getPlacesV2()` and `x-api-version=3` should be directed to `PlacesControllerV3#getPlacesV3()`

In normal spring code this usually works like this without any bean mapping issues:

```
@RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/places",
            produces = {"application/json", "application/problem+json"},
            headers = {"X-API-VERSION=2"}
    )
public ResponseEntity<PlaceResponseV2> getPlacesV2()
{}
```

However when trying to do it using then openapi codegenerator I only get the header as a parameter `getPlacesV2(Integer xAPIVERSION){}` but that is already too late since I need to make the switch between controllers before I get to a controller. This also causes a bean mapping error since spring can't differentiate between the mapped path in the two controllers PlacesControllerV2 and PlacesControllerV3.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/openapi/OSDM-online-api-v2.0.5-rc.yml"
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated-osdm-oas"
    apiPackage = "com.bene_system.osdm.facade.v2"
    modelPackage = "com.bene_system.osdm"
    library = "spring-boot"
    generateApiTests = false
    generateApiDocumentation = false
    configOptions = [
            interfaceOnly: "true",
            dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
    groupId = 'com.bene_system.osdm_facade'
    id = 'osdm-facade'
    skipValidateSpec = true
    logToStderr = true
    generateAliasAsModel = false
    enablePostProcessFile = false
    modelNameSuffix = 'V2'
    apiNameSuffix = 'V2'
```

And this my yaml file:

```
  /places:
    get:
      summary: Returns all places.
      operationId: getPlacesV2
      parameters:
      - name: Requestor
        in: header
        description: "The requestor header contains detailed information about who is calling the API. It can include information such as channel, organization, sales unit or workstation id and be used to configure e.g. the fare range provided to the caller. The content of the string is part of a bilateral contract by the two parties and not standardized by OSDM. It is recommend to encrypt the information transferred."
        required: true
        style: simple
        explode: false
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: Accept-Language
        in: header
        description: Describes the set of natural languages that are preferred for localized text in the response to the request (see RFC2616-sec14.4). Supporting English (en) is a must.
        required: false
        style: simple
        explode: false
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: traceparent
        in: header
        description: "The traceparent header describes the position of the incoming request in its trace graph in a portable, fixed-length format. Its design focuses on fast parsing. Every tracing tool MUST properly set traceparent even when it only relies on vendor-specific information in tracestate (see W3C Trace Context)."
        required: false
        style: simple
        explode: false
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: tracestate
        in: header
        description: The tracestate extends traceparent with vendor-specific data represented by a set of name/value pairs. Storing information in tracestate is optional (see W3C Trace Context).
        required: false
        style: simple
        explode: false
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: page
        in: query
        description: can be used for pagination
        required: false
        style: form
        explode: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: x-API-VERSION
        in: header
        description: Is used for versioning
        required: true
        style: simple
        explode: false
        schema:
          type: integer
          format: int32
      responses:
        "200":
          description: the requested places
          headers:
            Cache-Control:
              style: simple
              explode: false
              schema:
                type: string
                description: Resource is fairly persistent and has a medium time to live to allow short-term caching.
                default: "public, max-age=10000"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlaceResponse'
```

I tried setting an empty requestBody with content defined as `"application/json;X-API-Version=2"` like so:

```
requestBody:
content:
"application/json;X-API-Version=2":
schema:
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. This creates a header param in the @RequestParam annotation enabling versioning.

```
 - in: header
    name: X-API-VERSION
    required: true
    schema:
      default: 2
      type: integer
      x-version-param: true
    x-version-param: true
```